# PyTorch CNN gives different results

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, facial-identification

I am trying to make a face recognition model with PyTorch. My model performs well with both loss scores for training and validation close to 0. The problem is when I tested it using same input, it gives me different results like below:

[image: output 1]

and below

[image]

The left side is the true label and the right one is the prediction output. I set random seed and ran `model.eval()` before feeding the input to the model.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Please advise

Comment: Did you forget to add normalization in prediction?

Comment: @WbytheSea, I did.